# Words for something created "so far"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I wrote:

> The visual tool also executes the (**present**) wrapper program (**created so far**). The algorithm navigates the DOM-tree top-down to the highlighted node and **evaluates and shows** the related context variables to the user.

The wrapper program is created gradually, then I look for a word for the state when it's not complete yet. I suspect between **present** and **created so far** or any better word for this situation.

Moreover, I don't know how to combine *evaluate* and *show* when each takes different complements.

Comment: Does the user really need to know that the extraction algorithm is executed as it is created? Simplify, simplify!

Comment: What @Mick said. If you really do think the point is worth making, I suggest you dump ***present*** and refer to *the wrapper program **as currently** (or **presently**) implemented*. But since the implication is that the current implementation might be changed (and might perhaps not even use this algorithm at all at some point in the future) you should probably mention the current ***date*** as well. There's nothing wrong with ***evaluating and showing** (or **displaying**) **variables.***

Comment: What I find unclear is the phrase "executes the extraction algorithm *for the wrapper program*". Is it "execute...for" as in "executes on behalf of"? Or is "for" a kind of possessive, the algorithm belonging to the wrapper program?  or is "for" resultative: the algorithm that produces the wrapper program?

Comment: Also, please don't begin your contexts with a reference to an earlier context, e.g. "It".

Comment: ...evaluates the related context variables and shows *them* (or *their values*) to the user.

Comment: @TRomano you are right, actually the algorithm is itself the execution algorithm of the wrapper program. I modified the question. Suppose an interactive environment which assist the user to create the wrapper program.

Comment: @Mick yes, I want to describe a visual tool that helps the user to create a wrapper program incrementally.

Comment: @TRomano How about saying "*The visual tool also applies the extraction algorithm to the wrapper program*".

Comment: By **applies the algorithm to the wrapper program** do you mean "adds to  the wrapper program the code which implements the extraction algorithm"?  For me, an algorithm is an abstract thing, and it cannot be "added" to anything.

Comment: @Tromano the program is written by the user and specify under which conditions which elements must be extracted. An extraction algorithm takes this program (information) and extracts the specified data. Better say the algorithm applies the program to a web page.

Comment: @Ahmad If I understand you correctly, your visual tool constructs a set of rules describing how data should be extracted from a specified source, which set of rules  is supplied to an extraction engine as input, and then the extraction engine is pointed at the source of information whereupon it proceeds to extract data from it, according to those rules.

Comment: @tromano exactly!

Comment: @Ahmad. OK.  Where does the "wrapper program"  fit into that scenario?  Is the "wrapper" another name for the set of rules?

Comment: @TRomano Yes the wrapper program is the set of rules. "wrapper" could be the name of the whole software which extracts data from webpages, but the "wrapper program" is the name of set of rules. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_%28data_mining%29

Comment: I think **The visual tool is used to *assemble* a wrapper program** would be clearer than **... is used to create a wrapper program**; then you could say "the *partially assembled* wrapper program" or "the wrapper program assembled thus far..." or similar.